# Validation of hypens through regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to do a validator for a name.  The name can consist of alphabetical letter (big and small caps), space, and no more than 2 optional hyphens (but not consecutively).

For example, this is correct:

```
alksjdasdlfj 
alsjdf ajsdfl
lkj-asdfj alsdjflj
lksaldf asldjf-jasfd-alsdjf
```

This is incorrect:

```
asjdfkl-ajsdf-asdjf-alsdjf  (3 hyphens)
lasdjf--asdjfj (consecutive hyphens)
```

This is what I came up with:

```
(^[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z ]+\-?)*[a-zA-Z]$)|(^[a-zA-Z]*$)
```

But this regex does not limit the number of hyphens to just two occurrences.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Does it need to be a single regex?

Comment: I've tried with a negative look-ahead `^(?!.*-.*-.*-|.*-{2,}|.*- |.* -).*` (live: http://regex101.com/r/oZ8aM6).

Comment: Can someone have more than few names like Jean Claude Van Damme? Or you want to accept only `XX-XX-X X-X-X` pattern (there is max one space)?

Comment: Yes, preferably a single regex. And Jean Claude Van Damme is considered a valid name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming words can have only two hyphens which can't be written one after another then you want to make sure that there is at least one letter after each of them. In that case regex for such word can look like

```
[a-z]+(-[a-z]+){0,2}    //you will need to add case-insensitive flag
```

which means

```
[a-z]+  //it starts with at least one letter
(-[a-z]+){0,2} //and have max two of words starts with `-`
```

So to accept more of such strings (names) you need regex like

```
(?i)[a-z]+(-[a-z]+){0,2}( [a-z]+(-[a-z]+){0,2})*
  ^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  | mandatory first name  optional other names
  +---case insensitive flag, lets `a` match also `A`
```

Demo:

```
String data[] = { 
        "alksjdasdlfj", 
        "alsjdf ajsdfl",
        "lkj-asdfj alsdjflj", 
        "lksaldf asldjf-jasfd-alsdjf",
        "asjdfkl-ajsdf-asdjf-alsdjf", 
        "lasdjf--asdjfj", };
for (String s : data)
    System.out.println(s+ " : " + 
            s.matches("(?i)[a-z]+(-[a-z]+){0,2}( [a-z]+(-[a-z]+){0,2})*"));
```

Output:

```
alksjdasdlfj : true
alsjdf ajsdfl : true
lkj-asdfj alsdjflj : true
lksaldf asldjf-jasfd-alsdjf : true
asjdfkl-ajsdf-asdjf-alsdjf : false
lasdjf--asdjfj : false
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*(-[a-zA-Z ]+)?(-[a-zA-Z ]+)?$
```

You could make it a bit neater by repeating the group at most twice:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*(-[a-zA-Z ]+){0,2}$
```

It works like this: first, you have a letter and any number of letter/space characters. Then there are two optional groups (in parentheses: `(-[a-zA-Z ]+)?`) that can each start with a hyphen: this ensures that there are at most two hyphens. Each hyphen has to be followed by at least one letter/space, ensuring they're not consecutive.

If you want, you could also limit it so that the hyphens cannot be followed by a space.

Answer (score 0):

If RegEx is not a requirement, here is a non-RegEx function to do it:

```
private bool IsValid(string str)
{
    bool found = false;
    bool consecutive = false;
    foreach (char t in str)
    {
        if (!char.IsLetter(t) && t != '-' && t != ' ')
            return false;
        if (t == '-' && found)
        {
            consecutive = true;
            break;
        }
        if (t == '-' && !found)
        {
            found = true;
        }
        if (t != '-')
            found = false;
    }

    if (consecutive)
        return false;

    return str.Count(z => z == '-') <= 2;
}
```

Tested with your sample data and it works as expected!

and its Java version

```
private boolean isValid(String str)
{
    boolean found = false;
    boolean consecutive = false;
    for(char t : str.toCharArray())
    {
        if (!Character.isLetter(t) && t != '-' && t != ' ')
            return false;
        if (t == '-' && found)
        {
            consecutive = true;
            break;
        }
        if (t == '-' && !found)
        {
            found = true;
        }
        if (t != '-')
            found = false;
    }

    if (consecutive)
        return false;

    return str.chars().filter(z -> z == '-').count() <= 2;
}
```

Comment: Since question was tagged with Java and not with C# or whatever your original code is I edited your post a little. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Pshemo - For some reason I totally didn't see that it was a Java question. Thank you for editing my answer.

Comment: Are you sure that `if (!char.IsLetter(t))` will not prevent str to have `-`? `Character.isLetter` returns false for `-` which causes immediate return of false with code `if (!Character.isLetter(t)) return false;`.

Comment: I forgot to mention about spaces :)